# How do I add event listeners in JQuery for dynamically created links with the same class name?

Tags: jquery

I have been trying for the last couple days to get some code to work.  I have been researching the topic and I've narrowed down what I think is going on.  I have a program that dynamically creates links depending on a user action.

```
   <div id="parent><a class="delete-row" id="wow" href="javascript:void(0)">Del</a></div>
```

Now the problem is that the initial one that loads with the page loads just fine.  Any subsequent links that are created don't work as from what I understand the listeners are only loaded when the page loads.  This explains why the first one works, but any subsequent links do not fire in the DOM when they are clicked.

I tried the code below based on a tutorial I found on the internet.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-row').on('click', function(){
      $('<a class="delete-row" href="javascript:void(0)">Del</a>').appendTo('#parent');
      });
    });

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#parent").on('click', 'a', function() {
      console.log("Clicked.");
      });
    });
```

It doesn't recognize the parent click.  The only thing I'm wondering is if perhaps the fact that the links are all the same is preventing them from being recognized after the first one?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.  It's my understanding that the append function is supposed to be adding the listener when the add=row class name is clicked....It does kind of work...it's just that the parent block doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty  I will accept the answer provided by CertainPerformance.  I have determined that this is not the source of my issue.  I am using Django Formsets and there appears to be a frequently encountered issue with dynamically created formsets and JQuery/Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamically added elements need to be added as a descendent of the parent which has the listener on it. Try changing

```
.appendTo('body');
```

to

```
.appendTo('#parent');
```

because `#parent` has the listener. (The body doesn't have the listener.)

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-row').on('click', function() {
    $('<a class="delete-row" href="javascript:void(0)">Del</a>').appendTo('#parent');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parent").on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log("Clicked.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-row">add row</button>
<div id="parent"><a class=" delete-row " id="wow " href="javascript:void(0) ">Del</a></div>
```

Another approach would be to attach the listener to the body instead.

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete-row', () => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I made the change you suggested....changing to the parent reference....but still only the first clicked item is recognized.  The delete row.  Only the first one on the page is recognized and the subsequent ones do not show clicked in the log when I click them.  Is it because of the anchor tags being the same and their class name being the same maybe?

Comment: Works just fine here - try running the live snippet in the answer.

Comment: Yep I see it working just fine in the snippet.  It might be the way my program is creating the element...would that matter if it was being created as a string vs. an element in my JQuery program?

Comment: I think it might be working....Weird the way that Chrome is logging the Clicked output...It didn't show it until like the 5th click that it was in fact producing it.  Very wild.  I think it's fixed.....Will test more to confirm but thank you so much!!!!!!!!  I've been trying to fix this for 3 days.  Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Thanks again.  It appears to still not be working but I now know it's not attributed to the listener aspect.   I'm using Django Formsets....and it seems the problem lies within those at this time.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you edit a [MCVE] into your question illustrating the problem? I still can't reproduce the issue you're having - the code in the question plus adding the listener to the proper parent element appears to work as desired

Comment: I haven't been able to test this solution yet...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036000/how-to-handle-javascript-event-inside-a-inlineformset-factory-with-formset-media  But it would appear that this is essentially what I'm experiencing.  The new forms aren't responsive to the Javascript handler based on the way they're created with Django Formsets...Formsets are pretty complicated and not easily documented in this forum...The SO I reference here is a solid overview of the issue as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a great working example of how to set a listener for dynamic events.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-row').on('click', function(){
      $('<a class="delete-row" href="javascript:void(0)">Del</a>').appendTo('#parent');
      });
    });

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#parent").on('click', 'a', function() {
      console.log("Clicked.");
      });
    });
```

Turns out this was not the source of my issue but helped me rule it out for sure.