# How do I get Javascript Handler to recognize dynamically added forms via Formsets?

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

So after about 3 days of completely being demoralized over JQuery...come to figure out that there is an issue with Django formsets whereby if there are extra forms defined prior to the page load...all is right with the world.  If the user clicks to add forms....or the add button essentially...the dynamically loaded forms are not captured by Javascript or Jquery.  The data gets processed...but I am unable to manipulate the dynamically generated forms via Javascript or JQuery.  I tried to add event listeners programmatically but that didn't seem to help.

Essentially...I have a link that is generated by jquery.formset.js.

It looks like...

```
<a class="delete-row-budget" href="javascript:void(0)">Del</a>
```

It gets generated fine...but the issue is that it's invisible to JQuery and Javascript.  Has anyone else encountered this?  I did come across this issue which sounds identical but have not been able to get this solution to work.... [How to handle JavaScript event inside a inlineformset_factory with formset_media_js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036000/how-to-handle-javascript-event-inside-a-inlineformset-factory-with-formset-media)

My latest attempt at this has been to try to update jquery.formset.js so that the delete button is generated as an element....

```
        var delButtonHTML = document.createElement("a");
            delButtonHTML.classList.add(options.deleteCssClass);
            delButtonHTML.textContent = options.deleteText;
```

Then I have tried to add an event listener....

```
            delButtonHTML.addEventListener('click', listen, false);
```

But that's as far as I've gotten. I've had syntax issues and can't quite figure out how to add the listener properly.  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

What's so odd is that the events work fine if they are initially loaded with the form....but the dynamic events are not recognized.  From what I've read...this is expected behavior...just trying to confirm I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, in that question  from another page there they have `root.addEventListener('change', ev => {` so they added event handler on form itself if any changes occur inside form element it will trigger that event handler automatically .

Comment: @Swati Thank you for the thought.  I’ve tried pretty much everything I can think of.  Searched all day.  The only thought I have left is that the program that creates the links dynamically doesn’t have a listener.  I tried earlier today to add a listener to the program but I couldn’t get it to work.